# changing a method parameter with a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I'm doing a snake game in Java and I've met the following problem:

I want to be as generic as I can be, so I created a Board interface, later implemented by a GameBoard; and a BoardObject interface later implemented by Snake, Wall, FoodPackage.
In the BoardObject interface there's an abstract method generateObject(Board b) which is meant to generate an object on a specifical board.
But when I implement this, I want it to be generateObject(GameBoard b). How could I do it? I suppose that it will not be overridden this way, so I thought this escamotage:

```
generateObject(Board b){
   generateObject( (GameBoard) b);
}
```

where

```
generateObject(GameBoard b){
// this will do the real thing
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the right thing to do, because it will probably give me errors somehow (for example if I implement Board with another class, say GameBoardTwo, and pass a GameBoardTwo thru that method, what may happen?)

I really hope you can help me.

Comment: simple question: why? The object add itself to the board, no matter if it is a `GameBoard` or a `SomeOtherImplementingBoard`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Because the GameBoard contains some simple rules, e.g. how the snake will move or die, but if I wanted to change these rules I could just reimplement the Board with a different subclass.

Comment: Or wait... I think I've figured out your advice now. I'll just use Board abstract methods in generateObject(Board b) which are then implemented by a concrete GameBoard.
Thank you very much! I'll try this out.

Comment: You have to declare the needed methods in the Board interface and implement whatever you want in the Board. The Snake then adds itself on *some*  board, which probably *is* a GameBoard, but that is of no interest for the snake. You can simply hand in the GameBoard as Board and everything should work

Comment: that is exactly what I meant